# Async/Await operations happening out of expected order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to update a bunch of records in a database, based on IMDB results for a hobby site to learn Node and React. I'm fairly new to async/await code and promises as well, so I'm struggling.

Based on what I've read, this code should:

- Retrieve all my "TopMovies" records from my database
- Wait for all records to populate before continuing
- Call processing asynchronously to update some basic fields on each record from IMDB
- Save each individual record as part of it's async thread
- Return all processed records

Instead, I get the following console information:

```
[0] Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `rank`, `name`, `IMDBId`, `rating`, `genre`, `posterUrl`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `reviewerId`, `yearId` FROM `TopMovies` AS `TopMovie`;
[0] Movie count: 150
[0] All done
[0] Updated movie: Chef
[0] Executing (default): UPDATE `TopMovies` SET `rating`=3.5,`genre`='Adventure',`posterUrl`='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5NTYzNTA1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODIwODU1MTE@._V1_UY268_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg',`updatedAt`='2018-02-02 19:49:17.036 +00:00' WHERE `id` = 44
[0] Updated movie: The Champions
[0] Executing (default): UPDATE `TopMovies` SET `rating`=4.5,`genre`='10 October 2015 (USA) ',`posterUrl`='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTk5MjM2MjQ4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIxMDA5NzE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg',`updatedAt`='2018-02-02 19:49:17.092 +00:00' WHERE `id` = 87
[0] Updated movie: Trance
```

Note that it's Updating the records after it outputs "All done", and returns from the app.get() function. Ideally it would do more like:

```
[0] Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `rank`, `name`, `IMDBId`, `rating`, `genre`, `posterUrl`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `reviewerId`, `yearId` FROM `TopMovies` AS `TopMovie`;
[0] Movie count: 150
[0] Updated movie: Chef
[0] Executing (default): UPDATE `TopMovies` SET `rating`=3.5,`genre`='Adventure',`posterUrl`='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTY5NTYzNTA1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwODIwODU1MTE@._V1_UY268_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg',`updatedAt`='2018-02-02 19:49:17.036 +00:00' WHERE `id` = 44
[0] Updated movie: The Champions
[0] Executing (default): UPDATE `TopMovies` SET `rating`=4.5,`genre`='10 October 2015 (USA) ',`posterUrl`='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTk5MjM2MjQ4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjIxMDA5NzE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg',`updatedAt`='2018-02-02 19:49:17.092 +00:00' WHERE `id` = 87
[0] Updated movie: Trance
[0] All done
* Returns from app.get
```

What am I doing wrong, that makes it say "All done" before it processes any of the records? Here's the relevant code:

```
const imdb = require('imdb');
const _require = require('./models/index'),
  Year = _require.Year,
  Reviewer = _require.Reviewer,
  TopMovie = _require.TopMovie,
  ViewStat = _require.ViewStat,
  Op = _require.Sequelize.Op;

app.get('/imdb_import', (req, res) => {
  const UpdateMovies = async () => {
    const topMovies = await TopMovie.findAll();
    console.log("Movie count: " + _.size(topMovies));

    // await topMovies.forEach(async topMovie => {
    //   await updateMovieDetails(topMovie);
    // });
    await Promise.all(topMovies.map(async(topMovie) => {
      await updateMovieDetails(topMovie);
    }));

    console.log("All done");
    return topMovies;
  };

  const updateMovieDetails = topMovie => {
    return imdb(topMovie.get('IMDBId'), (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
      }
      if (data) {
        topMovie.posterUrl = data.poster;
        topMovie.rating = Math.round(data.rating) / 2;
        if (data.genre) {
          topMovie.genre = data.genre[0];
        }
        topMovie.save();
        console.log("Updated movie: " + topMovie.name);
      }
    });
  };

  UpdateMovies()
    .then((data) => res.status(200).json(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

The code for this project can be found here, in the 'async_imdb' branch: https://github.com/mandreko/ov_stats/tree/async_imdb if anyone wants to run it locally

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await updateMovieDetails(topMovie);` does not accomplish anything in this code.  Remember, `await` does not stop the containing function from finishing and returning a promise.  It only affects code within the function.

So, if you were hoping to use this to sequence your operations, it does not do that.  Further because you aren't returning anything from your `.map()` callback the promise from `updateMovieDetails(topMovie)` isn't getting back to `Promise.all()` so it isn't waiting for them.

Change this:

```
await Promise.all(topMovies.map(async(topMovie) => {
  await updateMovieDetails(topMovie);
}));
```

to this:

```
await Promise.all(topMovies.map((topMovie) => {
  return updateMovieDetails(topMovie);
}));
```

And, then the `Promise.all()` will wait for all the `updateMovieDetails()` calls to finish.

In addition, `updateMovieDetails()` does not return a promise that is linked to it's activity so doing `Promise.all()` on those doesn't accomplish anything.

You can manually promisify the `imbdb()` function and then return the resulting promise from that like this:

```
const util = require('util');
// make promsified version of imdb()
const imdbPromise = util.promisify(imdb);

const updateMovieDetails = topMovie => {
    return imdbPromise(topMovie.get('IMDBId')).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        topMovie.posterUrl = data.poster;
        topMovie.rating = Math.round(data.rating) / 2;
        if (data.genre) {
          topMovie.genre = data.genre[0];
        }
        console.log("Updated movie: " + topMovie.name);
        topMovie.save();
      }
    });
};
```

---

Here's the accumulation of what I'm recommending:

```
const util = require('util');
// make promsified version of imdb()
const imdbPromise = util.promisify(imdb);

app.get('/imdb_import', (req, res) => {
    const UpdateMovies = async () => {
      const topMovies = await TopMovie.findAll();
      console.log("Movie count: " + _.size(topMovies));

      await Promise.all(topMovies.map(updateMovieDetails);

      console.log("All done");
      return topMovies;
    };

    const updateMovieDetails = topMovie => {
        return imdbPromise(topMovie.get('IMDBId')).then(data => {
          if (data) {
            topMovie.posterUrl = data.poster;
            topMovie.rating = Math.round(data.rating) / 2;
            if (data.genre) {
              topMovie.genre = data.genre[0];
            }
            console.log("Updated movie: " + topMovie.name);
            return topMovie.save();
          }
        });
    };

    UpdateMovies()
      .then((data) => res.status(200).json(data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: When I remove that await, I still get the same out-of-order operations.

Comment: @mandreko - `Promise.all()` is a parallel tool.  It runs all your async operations at the SAME time, there is no guarenteed execution order.  If you want to sequence them, then use a `for` loop and `await` each one in the loop.  Hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve.  What exactly is your goal here with regards to ordering?

Comment: Promise.all() can totally run them all parallel. They don't have to be updated in any specific order. However, what I'm trying to achieve, is for it to return the updated records from the main app.get() main function call. Right now, it returns immediately after the movie count and "All done", and then afterwards goes through and updates all the records.

Comment: @mandreko - Well `updateMovieDetails()` doesn't return a promise so trying to use `await` on it or sending it's result to `Promise.all()` doesn't do anything.  You need to "promisify" that function.  That's actually the bigger miss here.

Comment: How could I change it to have the expected outcome? If I have it return topMovie.save(), it doesn't do it either.

Comment: @mandreko - You need to rewrite `updateMovieDetails()` using promises instead of plain callbacks so it returns a promise that is linked to its async activities.  `Promise.all()` only does something useful if you feed it an array of promises that are tied to the actual async activities you are trying to coordinate.  I don't know all the APIs you're' using in that function to know which ones might already have promise interfaces you can use or which ones have to be promisified by you so you can use a promisified version.

Comment: If the imdb library only offers this callback method, is that possible without switching libraries or re-writing it?

Comment: @mandreko - You can "promisify" any function yourself.  For functions that follow the node.js async calling convention (single callback as the last argument that takes (err, result) as two parameters), then you can use `util.promisify()` to make a promisified version of the function.  I'll take a look at how you would do that for your current code, but I may run into APis I don't know.

Comment: @mandreko - I added a promisifed version of `updateMovieDetails()` to my answer.

Comment: I tried the promisified version, and it still says "All done", returns the data to express un-updated, then performs the update on each movie record :(

Comment: @mandreko - Ok, we need to work on `topMovie.save()` and get that linked into the promise.  What does that return?  Does it return a promise.  Does it accept a callback to know when it's done?  I'm flying blind, not knowing all these APIs.

Comment: @mandreko - At this point, I also need to see a fresh copy of what code you're actually running that incorporates these changes so I can see if you've done everything we've discussed according to plan.  Please add that as an edit to the end of your answer.  I think maybe you're missing something we've discussed in the code you're running.

Comment: feel free to check out the code here: https://github.com/mandreko/ov_stats/tree/async_imdb  it's not a very complicated app, as I'm still learning all the technologies involved. Be sure to get the 'async_imdb' branch

Comment: @mandreko - What I see here: https://github.com/mandreko/ov_stats/blob/async_imdb/server.js does not incorporate ANY of the changes I've recommended.  Not sure what good that does me.

Comment: @mandreko - I summarized what I'm recommending in one code block at the end of my answer.  That's what I think you should be running.

Comment: @mandreko - Where did you leave this?  Is my recommendation working for you now?

Comment: That code snippet totally worked! Now I just have to read more so I can understand it better. Promises are hard.